# Flatpak: command not found

Tags: flatpak

I have built a flatpak package out of my application. However, flatpak-builder in the end complains:

```
Error: Command 'executable' not found
```

Where executable is the name of my program, which I have specified in my manifest as `"command": "executable"`.
When I check in the build folder, my executable is in `build-folder/files/executable`. (`files` is auto-generated and seems to  be the base installation directory, all the libraries get put in the `lib` folder below there).
When I change the command to e.g. `/executable`, the package gets created.
When test-running the application, I have to specify the full path to the executable for it to run:

```
flatpak-builder --run bin org.myorg.executable.json build-folder/files/executable
```

(when I just specify `executable` here instead of `build-folder/files/executable`, it tells me `bwrap: execvp executable: No such file or directory`).

However, when I install the flatpak via a local repo , `flatpak run org.myorg.executable` shows

```
bwrap: execvp /executable: No such file or directory
```

(where `executable` is the name of my executable). Of course, I suppose it should just be `executable` instead of `/executable`, but flatpak-builder won't create a package with that value!

So, what am I doing wrong here, how can I create a working package with flatpak-builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake - my executable should have gone into the `bin` folder, now it works...